# Vaadin23 IntegerField disable value change on mouse scroll button

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin23

Is it possible to disable the value change effect on the mouse scroll for the `IntegerField` component? If so, could you please show me how it is possible?

Answer (score 3):

The scrolling behaviour comes from the browser and there isn't any direct feature for disabling it. It's still possible to do it with the workaround of listening to client-side scroll events on the element and preventing the default behaviour.

```
numberField.getElement().executeJs("this.focusElement.addEventListener('mousewheel', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); })");
```